# suppressing pop up - do you want to replace the destination cells

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to convert a csv file to a tab delimited excel file. My code is working but while doing so I am getting a pop-up saying
"Do you want to replace the destination cells". I want to suppress this pop up.

```
file = "C:\P_TEST\Size_test.csv"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

txt = fso.OpenTextFile(file).ReadAll

fso.OpenTextFile(file, 2).Write Replace(Replace(txt, "¬", vbTab), Chr(34), "")

'Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'Calls the File System Object  

Const xlDelimited = 1
Const xlNormal = -4143 

Dim Excel
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With Excel
    .Workbooks.Open "\\wpkb0203\pq2\PIM\inbound\PIM_TEST\SizeGuideLookup_test.csv"
    .Sheets(1).Columns("A").TextToColumns .Range("A1"), xlDelimited, , , , True  'semicolon-delimited

    .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs .ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\SizeGuideLookup_test", xlNormal
    .Quit

'    fso.DeleteFile("\\wpkb0203\pq2\PIM\inbound\PIM_TEST\SizeGuideLookup_test.csv") 'Deletes the file throught the DeleteFile function 
End With
```

I tried to use the following code to suppress it and does but then csv file does not convert from a ¬ delimited to a tab delimited Excel file.

```
Sub()    '
Application.DisplayAlerts = False   
file = "C:\P_TEST\Size_test.csv"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

txt = fso.OpenTextFile(file).ReadAll

fso.OpenTextFile(file, 2).Write Replace(Replace(txt, "¬", vbTab), Chr(34), "")

'Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 'Calls the File System Object  

Const xlDelimited = 1
Const xlNormal = -4143 

Dim Excel
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With Excel
    .Workbooks.Open "C:\P_TEST\Size_test.csv"
    .Sheets(1).Columns("A").TextToColumns .Range("A1"), xlDelimited, , , , True  'semicolon-delimited

    .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs .ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\SizeLookup_test", xlNormal
    .Quit

End With
End Sub
```

Here is the csv input file. First line is header. Again, my code is converting csv to tab delimited Excel. i just need to suppress the pop up.

```
Id¬Group1¬Size Value
65743¬StrucW¬Womens General
76544¬StrucB¬Beauty
```

After converting to Excel, it becomes

```
Id  Group1  Size Value
65743   StrucW  Womens General
76544   StrucB  Beauty
```